# Python list basic manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was attempting to write a very basic function that can move every element in the list one index earlier. And I think I am actually pretty close to the result I want.

For example if a list is

```
l = [1, 2, 4, 5, 'd']
```

I want it to be like that afterwards

```
l = [2, 4, 5, 'd', 1]
```

The reality of my code

```
l = [2, 4, 5, 1, 1]
```

Here is my code, I just don't know what is happening here after a lot of random attempts on changing the code...

Thank you guys in advance!

```
def cycle(input_list):
count = 0
while count < len(input_list):
     tmp = input_list[count - 1]
     input_list[count - 1] = input_list[count]
     count+=1
```

Comment: You never use the tmp-variable. You need to define it outside the while-loop and then actually use it

Comment: `l.append(l.pop(0))` :)

Answer (score 9):

You could do this (in place):

```
l.append(l.pop(0))
```

In function form (makes a copy):

```
def cycle(l):
    ret = l[:]
    ret.append(ret.pop(0))
    return ret
```

Comment: This does not make a copy of `l`, you need `ret = l[:]` if you want to create a copy.

Comment: @Holt or alternatively `ret = list(l)`.

Comment: @Holt Thanks. I forgot that it just assigns a new handle/variable. Changed it.

Answer (score 2):

As a python developer, I really cant resist typing this one liner

`newlist = input[start:]  +  input[:start]`

where `start` is the amount by which you have to rotate the list

Ex :

`input = [1,2,3,4]`

you want to shift array by `2` , `start = 2`

`input[2:] = [3,4]`

`input[:2] = [1,2]`

`newlist = [3,4,1,2]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do. Get the first item of the list, delete it, then add it back to the end.

```
def cycle(input_list):
    first_item = input_list.pop(0)  #gets first element then deletes it from the list 
    input_list.append(first_item)  #add first element to the end
```

Comment: `pop(0)` already returns the item, there's no need to get first_item separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `while` or the `for` statements.
Using `for`:

```
    newList = []
    for index in range(1, len(list)):
        newList.append(list[index])
    newList.append(list[0])
```

Using `while`:

```
newList = []
index = 1
while index < len(list):
    newList.append(list[index])
    index += 1
newList.append(list[0])
```

You'll be able to move any list one element to the left :)

Example:

```
def move(list):
    newList = []
    for index in range(1, len(list)):
        newList.append(list[index])
    newList.append(list[0])
    return newList

list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'd']
list = move(list)

print(list)
>>>[2, 3, 4, 5, 'd', 1]
```